# group_concat creates a issue for fetching more then one record

Tags: mysql, group-concat

I am facing an issue related to group_concat because when I am using this the total record can't fetch from the table based in the transactionID 
Here is my stored procedure code. In this I am using a split function called strSplit.

```
BEGIN

DECLARE iCount int;

DECLARE i int;

DECLARE txn VARCHAR(65000);

DECLARE txId VARCHAR(17);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE report_transaction (client_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, productName VARCHAR(200), itxnId VARCHAR(100),PRIMARY KEY(client_id));

select count(distinct(tt.TxnId)) into iCount from tbl_transaction tt;

SELECT group_concat(distinct((tt.TxnId)) separator ', ') product into txn  from tbl_transaction tt;

SET i=1;

WHILE i<iCount+1 DO

select strSplit(txn, ',', i) into txId;

SELECT RTRIM(LTRIM(txId));

 INSERT INTO report_transaction(productName,itxnId) select group_concat((tt.ProductName) separator ',') products,tt.TxnId from tbl_transaction tt where tt.TxnId= txId;

    SET i = i + 1;

END WHILE;

     SELECT * FROM report_transaction;
     drop table report_transaction;

END
```

I want result like a table record but it shows only first record and then other fields are null.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want can be done by a single query:

```
INSERT INTO report_transaction(productName,itxnId)
    select group_concat((tt.ProductName) separator ',') as products, tt.TxnId
    from tbl_transaction tt
    group by tt.TxnId;
```

You don't need the temporary table to store the ids, or to trim or split anything.

In general, you'll get much better performance by using SQL queries when they are appropriate.

By the way, if you do need to iterate through rows in a table, then you should learn about cursors.

Comment: You should modify your question, or ask another one, that includes sample data and results.

Comment: Sir my problem is the function group_concat produce output for once in where condition how to solve it